# Linearize non-linear constraint in LP program

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, gurobi

Is there any method to linearize following constraint

```
m.addConstrs(y[t]==(x[t]+z[t])/(x[t]*2+z[t]*5), for t in T)
```

Thank you

Comment: Please give us some more context. Are `x` and `z` binary or whole numbers, for example?

Comment: Rewrite as `y[t]*((x[t]*2+z[t]*5))==(x[t]+z[t])`. Depending on the details the quadratic terms may (or may not) be linearized. Note that some solvers can handle quadratic terms directly.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot x and z are continous variables